# setting javascript variable name from a variable

Tags: javascript

Hi is it possible to set a `var` name from another variable?

Such as I have the `var test` with different numbers each time the function is called so I want the number to be a variable name e.g. var test contains ' 1 ' so the new variable would be `var 1`. I then want to add a word to this number "word" to make the new variable become `var 1word`.

```
var newNumber = 1;
var newNumber += 'word';
       ^ becomes ' 1 '
the new var name becomes ' 1word '
```

edit:

```
function getNumber(newNumber) //  Gets a number, for this example say its the number '1' 
    {

        var newNumber += "something";  //The new varaible will be named "1something" (something can be any word)

    }
```

Hope I haven't made it sound too confusing, thanks.

Comment: In this particular case, that's a stupid idea.  There is no point in dynamically changing the name of a single local variable.  Just use a generic name.  However, there are other cases (involving multiple variables) where this is a very powerful technique.

Comment: Note that you can't begin a variable name with a numeric character in Javascript.

Comment: Am not trying to rename a variable, am trying to use the value of a variable to create a new variable with the value as the name.

Comment: @Robusto I wouldnt begin with a number, this is just an example.

Comment: You misunderstood.  There is no point in customizing the name of your new variable.

Comment: @SLaks am not customising? Am creating a totally new variable, am just getting the value from the variable already created to use as the new varaible's name.

Comment: Why don't you use a simple name for the new variable?

Comment: There would be more than one variable, so rather than typing them out I wanted it to dynamically create them.

Comment: @Elliott: Your pseudocode says "the new var name becomes ' 1word '
" and your comment says 'The new varaible will be named "1something"'. Apparently when you say "name" you mean "value"; silly me. In any case, your example makes it hard to tell what you really mean.

Comment: The "word" is just any word, in the example the word is something. Sorry for the confusion its hard to explain.
Make a new varaible and set the name of the new variable from the value of another varaible.

Answer (score 5):

Everything in Javascript is basically just an associative array. This means you can use array access notation and dot notation more or less interchangeably. Array access notation provides the feature you are looking for:

```
object["name"]="foo"
```

will set a name property on the given object.

If you want to create a global variable then use the window object

```
window["name"]="foo"
```

You can also use an expression or a variable in the square brackets

```
window[someVaribale]="foo";
window["name_" + someVariable]="foo";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can put the variables in an object and index the object using string keys.

For example:

```
var myData = { };
myData.x1 = 42;
alert(myData["x" + 1]);
```

You can also initialize the object using object notation:

```
var myData = { key: 42 };
```

Answer (score 3):

Far as I can understand, you want to create a variable that's named after the *contents* of another variable.

Not sure if you can do this directly, but you can do it pretty painlessly using objects.

```
var obj = new Object();
obj['original'] = 'name';
obj[obj]['original']] = 'another name';
```

The object now has *this* structure:

```
{
  'original': "name",
  'name': "another name" #variable named after original's contents
}
```

Comment: Thanks that what I wanted , I havent used objects before could you give me a quick example how I would alert the new object/variable created?

Comment: alert(obj['name']) or alert(obj[obj['original']])

Comment: Also, go here for docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object

Comment: answer is very good. Thanks. Only in the 3rd line of **obj** , the first enclosing box-bracket **']'** won't be present. means it should be like;
`var obj = new Object();
obj['original'] = 'name';
obj[obj['original']] = 'another name';`

Answer (score 2):

There's a simple way to achieve this, if you store all your variables inside an object/array. Remember, in javascript, arrays are objects, objects are objects etc :p

```
var mystuff = {}; // new object literal

var numVariables = 10;

for (var i = numVariables - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    var newkey          = i + "_my_index";
    mystuff[newkey]     = "some stuff";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using numeric "variables" like in your exemple (var 1; var 2;)
you should use Array;

```
var list=[]; //declaration

list[1]="something"; //create a "variable" 1 with 'something' inside

list[2]="other thing"; //create another variable

var name=3;
var value="Hello";

list[name]=value; //works too

alert( list[1] ); //something
```

if you're using words as "keywords" you should use objects instead of Arrays

```
var list={}; //declaration

list["car1"]="Honda";
list["car2"]="Toyota";
list["fuit"]="Apple";

var name="greeting";
var value="Hello";

list[name]=value; //works too

alert( list["car2"] ); //Toyota
```

hope you understood.

Answer (score 1):

We need more of an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish. This looks like a really bad idea. Most likely you really should just used a named index array. Eg.

```
var stuff = {}
stuff[1] = "one";
stuff["name"] = "david";
```

Comment: Say am passing a number to a fucntion, this is then stored in a variable. The value of the "number" (passed to function) becomes the name of the new variable.

Comment: I think, umm, Mr Design, was suggesting this this is an X-Y problem. You think that variable variables (Y) will solve a problem (X), but you don't say what X is. (Variable variables are, BTW, evil nightmares that are horrible to maintain that should be avoided).

Comment: There is probably a better way to do what that doesn't involve determining variable names on the fly.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused by your question but it seems like you want to change a variables name which cannot be done.  You can create a new variable with the desired name and assign it whatever value you want.

My question is why would you want to do this?

Comment: I have a function which passes elementIDs. I want to create a new variable with the name of the value in the elementID.

Comment: I think you might be better off using an array, an object or some sort of loop.  Without seeing your code I can't say for sure though.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve this with the builtin method:
eval( "your javascript code here" );

so maybe in your case it would be something like:
eval( "var yourNewName = \"" + yourOldVarValue + "\"");
then nullify your old variable.

But as the others express, I can't see why or in which case you would want to rename a variable (unless its for some weird hacking trickery lol).

[not tested, so this eval may not even work :S]

Comment: This is a very bad pratice, avoid this.