# Dynamic variables names in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, dynamic

I have variable:

```
var variableDynamic = 1;
// or    
var variableDynamic = 1 + i++;
```

Is there any way to use that to create dynamic variable names, for example something like this:

```
var variableName + variableDynamic = {};
// or
var (variableName + variableDynamic) = {};
```

I know what I wrote above is absurd, but this is to explain the idea. Is it possible?

---

Ok, what I want to do to create element (upload form) every time user click on add new file group, everything is working fine except that plugin that I use for it need special variable for each upload form to trigger upload button (.uploadStoredFiles();).

This is rough code I did:

```
    $('#addOneMoreFileOrGroup').on('click', function(){

    var latestFileUploaderId = parseInt($('.well-large .file-uploader').last().attr('id').split('-')[2]) + 1;

    $('.well-large .control-group:last').after('<div class="control-group deal-type-online">  \
        <label class="control-label">File / File Group Title:</label> \
        <div class="controls"> \
            <input class="span4 file-title" type="text"> \
            <span class="question label label-warning" data-title="File / Group Name:" data-content="Name for your file or group of related files (for example your brand logotype in different file formats)." data-original-title="">?</span> \
            <div id="file-uploader-' + latestFileUploaderId + '" class="file-uploader"></div> \
        </div> \
    </div>');

    var HERE_I_NEED_DYNAMIC_VAR = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-' + latestFileUploaderId + ''),
        action: 'do-nothing.htm',
        autoUpload: false,
        debug: true,
        uploadButtonText: '<i class="icon icon-plus"></i> Select Files...',
        onSubmit: function() {

            $('#file-uploader-' + latestFileUploaderId + ' .qq-uploader').after('<button id="file-uploader-trigger-' + latestFileUploaderId + '" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="icon-upload icon-white"></i> Upload now</button>');

            $('#file-uploader-trigger-' + latestFileUploaderId + '').on('click', function() {

                if($(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.file-title').val() !== '') {
                    HERE_I_NEED_DYNAMIC_VAR.uploadStoredFiles();
                } else {

                    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('error');

                }

            });

        }
    });

});

}
```

Comment: is an array ou tof the question?

Comment: In what situation would you want to do this?

Comment: So at the end I will have result of **var variableName1 = {}** or **var variableName(N+) = {}**

Comment: I dont know how many items will be in array, they will be dynamically added.

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935146/setting-javascript-variable-name-from-a-variable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8525221/programmatically-setting-the-name-of-a-variable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12678470/variable-name-made-of-a-variable-value

Comment: Every duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+dynamic+variable+names

Comment: I am really struggling with that and think I did lost somewhere :)

Comment: @KevinBrydon Tons of reasons. One, for example, is if you were making a mini coding thing online where users can define their own variables.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221108/how-to-get-random-variables-value-in-javascript/35250618#35250618

Answer (score 32):

In JavaScript, an object's properties can be access either by `obj.prop` or `obj['prop']`.

In the global scope, all variables are children of the `window` property. So you'll be able to do:

```
var variableDynamic = 'Test';
window['variableName' + variableDynamic] = 'your value';
```

Check out [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUpsL/).

However, if you'd like to limit the scope of this variable to a function, you would have to define a parent object and use this in place of `window`.

Answer (score 16):

You can create dynamic variables with `eval`.

```
eval("dynamic" + i + " = val[i]");
```

Also have a look at this: [Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name)

Comment: This is elegant and I like it very much.  Was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5):

To add to FAngels answer, you may use bracket notation anywhere. This means that in addition to using `window['var']`, you can use `this['var']`.

Answer (score 4):

For this you can use `eval()`. But `eval()` is evil. You should use an array for things like this.

Example:

```
var i = 1337;
eval('var myvar' + i + ' = \'value\';');

alert(myvar1337);
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `eval()` is evil necessarily - it just gets misused sometimes.  It's job is to take a string and "**eval**uate" it into JavaScript code ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)), so **iff** you do need to set variables dynamically `eval()` is one method for doing so:

```
var t = 't';
var four = '4';
eval('var ' + (t + four) + ' = "some value";');
console.log(t4);

// returns "some value" to the console
```

There are probably better methods for effecting dynamic variable+value pairs, not least because **eval**uated code-strings are implemented at the global level, but the above does work.  The question is, is it the best method for what you want to achieve(?). See [this 2013 blog post from NCZOnline](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2013/06/25/eval-isnt-evil-just-misunderstood/) for a discussion of `eval()'.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure abote how that could be done in function scope, but global variable could be created like this:

```
window[variableName + variableDynamic] = {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your can use eval function

```
var data = "anyVariableName";
eval("var temp_" + data + "=123;");
alert(temp_anyVariableName);
```

Or you can Use Global `window` object, or `this`:

window:

```
var data = "anyVariableName";
window["temp_" + data] = 123;
alert(window["temp_" + data]); //123
```

or using dot

```
var data = "anyVariableName";
window.data = 123;
alert(window.data); //123
```

this:

```
ar data = "anyVariableName";
this["temp_" + data] = 123;
alert(this["temp_" + data]); //123
```

or using dot

```
var data = "anyVariableName";
this.data = 123;
alert(this.data); //123
```

A Real life example:

```
var tasksTableNameRandom = 'tasksTable_' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5);
console.log('Tasks Table Object name: ' + tasksTableNameRandom);
this.tasksTableNameRandom = $('#tasks-data-table').DataTable({
..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create dynamic variable names in javascript, but you can set object attributes by string. So if you create your dynamic variables as attributes of an object, you can accomplish your goal.