# Dynamic variable in loop javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to create a dynamic variable in the loop.
I found something about eval and window but I don't know how to use this.

This is my loop and i want to create a 9 variables names from m1 to m9. I mean that the name of variable must be m1 to m9

```
for(i=1; i<10; i++){

  var m+i = "Something"

}
```

Please help me with this. Really appreciate.

Comment: You really shouldn't, use an array instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291554/dynamic-variables-names-in-javascript

Comment: Why would you do this rather than simply using existing array or object syntax?

Comment: Yes, you can indeed do this with `eval`. But *should* you do it? It's almost *always* better to use an array and use `m[0]` to `m[8]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to create 9 variables.  Trust me.  You want to create an object.

```
var m = {};
for(var i=1; i<10; i++){
    m[i] = "Something";
}
```

You can also create an array (`m = []`), but since you are starting at `1` and not `0`, I'd suggest an object.

Comment: I would go for the array as it has numbered indices !

Comment: If the OP doesn't need to start at 1 (for some reason) then, I'd agree @adeneo, but Rocket's solution already states the reasoning for using an object is tied to the OP's code stating it starts at 1. Of course, it'd also be easier to advise the OP if they could explain /why/ they felt the need to have dynamic ordered variables in the first place.

Comment: @adeneo: I originally had the answer with an array, but I changed to an object, because in this case `m[0]` would be unset, and I was unsure if that would be a problem here.  What if his `i` started at `10` or `100`?  That is why I used an object.

Comment: @MattiasBuelens: Thanks for editing the post.  I copied and pasted the OP's code, so I forgot to fix the `var` :-)

Answer (score 2):

But if you still want to create 9 variables, despite all that, you still can:

```
for(i=1; i<10; i++){
  eval('var m'+i+'='+i)
}
```

(And yes, you shouldn't).

Comment: This is true.  You *can* do it, but it's not suggested :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
var object = {};     
var name = "m";
for(i=1; i<10; i++){
  object[name+i] = "Something";
}
console.log(object.m1); // "Something", same for m2,m3,m4,m5...,m9
```

However consider if the `"m"` is really necessary, arrays are way faster:

```
var array = [];
for(i=1; i<10; i++){
  array.push("Something");
}
console.log(array[0]); // "Something", same for 1,2,...,8
```