# Require Classes in AMD Style From a Variable Value?

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have 100s of classes from which I have to require Dojo class depending upon user selection. To boil it down, I have to require a Dojo class on basis of string value selected by user.

For instance if user selects a **truck** icon, I get **truck** and I have a class named **truck**.

Sync loader style can load it like

```
var userSelection = "Truck";
var myVeh = require("Vehicles/"+userSelection); 
var veh = new myVeh('Truck 4', 15000); 
veh.honk();
```

Dojo good practice recommends using  AMD loader to make sure classes is loaded before you make use of it.

```
require([
        "Vehicles/Truck",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Truck
      ) { ...... });
```

I want to stick with AMD style loading but

**how can I require classes in AMD style from a variable value to be used in callback?**

**What if I load with first non-AMD method? What are pros and cons?***

I have tried 
[Use dynamic variable names in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript) and [Dynamic variables names in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291554/dynamic-variables-names-in-javascript). They all suggest window and [] methods but none worked for me.

I am using Dojo 1.10.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

01) You can require your dojo classes (in the following example module Truck.js) using `require`, after the module is loaded a callback is executed passing as argument your dojo class.

Below an example which demonstrate `require` and a callback function.

```
require('Vehicles/Truck', function(Truck){
    var myTruck= new Truck('Truck 4', 15000);
});
```

You can specify more dynamically which module to load using:

```
var userSelection = 'Truck';
require('Vehicles/' + userSelection, function(Truck){
    var myTruck= new Truck('Truck 4', 15000);
});
```

02) Supposing your `Truck.js` is a AMD module, both your approaches (as mentionated in your question) are actually using `AMD` loading.

You can read more about `require` here: 
https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/require.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.