# Besides eval or document, is there a better way to create dynamic variable names from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, variables, dynamic

I am looking for a way to create an array in js/ts that contains a list of environment names. I want to loop over that array and use the array value as variable names in the body of the closure.

I would like to do something like (I know this won't work):

```
const envs = [ dev, test, uat, stage, prod ]

for (i = 1; i < envs.length; i++) {
    const envs[i] = `prefix${envs[i]}`;
}
```

I have seen where you can use eval like:

```
let k = 'value';
let i = 0;
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    eval('var ' + k + i + '= ' + i + ';');
}
```

Which would output:

```
console.log("value1=" + value1); // value1=1 
console.log("value2=" + value2); // value2=2
console.log("value3=" + value3); // value3=3
console.log("value4=" + value4); // value4=4
```

Is there another way to do this without using eval? I know people will ask, so the reason I don't want to use eval is that we use a code scanner that will flag the use of eval and we have to explain false positives constantly.

**Edit**
To clarify a little more: I am trying to create a variable so I can reference it later in my code.  So while the `console.log`s above show the value, it is more important for me to be able to reference the name later on. an example might be `newThing(envs[i] + i, other, params)`.

Also, I am trying to stay away from things like `window` and `document` as those will differ depending on where the code is run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic variables names in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291554/dynamic-variables-names-in-javascript)

Comment: See also ["Variable" variables in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use an object to store your variables which would be much *[safer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)* and you do not have to rely on `eval`. Something like:

```js
const envs = ['dev', 'test', 'uat', 'stage', 'prod'];
const resEnvs = {};

for (let i = 0; i < envs.length; i++) {
  resEnvs[envs[i]] = `prefix${envs[i]}`;
}

console.log(resEnvs);
// And simply use them as per requirement.
console.log(resEnvs.dev);

/* Edit usage*/
function newThing(envVar, other, params) {
    console.log(`Env: ${envVar}, Other: ${other}, Params: ${params}`);
}

for (let i = 0; i < envs.length; i++) {
    newThing(resEnvs[envs[i]], 'otherValue', 'paramsValue');
}
```

---

#### Edit:

You can also access the values using the bracket notation, which is useful when you need to loop over them or reference them dynamically:

```js
console.log(resEnvs['dev']); // "prefixdev"
console.log(resEnvs['test']); // "prefixtest"
```

So, for your `newThing(envs[i] + i, other, params)` example, you can use:

```js
newThing(resEnvs[envs[i]], other, params);
```

Comment: I think I would still need to loop over the Object to create variables that can be referenced later in the code.  I edited the original post as I wanted to clarify that I wanted to reference the variable names created before later on in the code.

Comment: I appreciate the edit.  Wouldn't this only pass the output of  `resEnvs[envs[i]]` which would be the name of the variable, but not the value?

Comment: @BangsKeyboards this is the value of the environment which you can leverage anywhere in the code. If you run the snippet above, you'll see the `prefixDev`, etc. will be passed. This is called `bracket notation` of accessing dynamic properties. Try running the snippet once

Comment: @BangsKeyboards Also for reference read this:https://javascript.info/object#square-brackets and about computed properties

Comment: Awesome!  Very well documented and thought out answers.  I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a web browser, your global scope is the `window` object. To write code that works everywhere, use the `globalThis` object, which will be the window object in the browser context, and the `global` object in node.js.

```js
for (let i=1; i<5; i++) globalThis[`value${i}`] = i

console.log(value1, value2, value3, value4);

['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4']
  .forEach(varName => console.log(`${varName} is ${globalThis[varName]}`))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this can answer your question, but if I understood well, you may need the string Enums in TypeScript.

This, of course, only applies if you can use TypeScript in your project.
A TS enum will be transpiled into a JS object.
Note : TS enum can still be referenced from a plain JS file (it will see it as an object).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums
https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_enums.php

```
enum EnvironmentEnum {
  Dev = "Dev",
  Test = "Test",
  Prod = "Prod"
};

const Environments = Object.values(EnvironmentEnum);

// logs "Dev"
console.log(EnvironmentEnum.Dev);

// logs "Test"
console.log(EnvironmentEnum.Test);

// logs the entire list
console.log(Environments);
```